# Virtual TCP-IP testing tool free online?

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

Does anyone know if there is a free tool for testing TCP/IP socket communications?

I am developing code to connect to an industrial printer which uses TCP/IP comms. and would like to get started prior to actually having the hardware.
It would be great if there was either a tool I could install locally on Windows10 or even an free online tool that I could send packets to and have echo back or display the bytes I sent, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start a local server using netcat. Try running `nc -l -p 1234` to listen on port 1234.

You can also write a simple C# application that listens for socket connections, accepts them and prints them on the console.